# Is the non-negativity of a potential preserved in the limit?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

If $\{ Y_t, 0 \leq t < \infty \}$ is a non-negative supermartingale such that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} E(Y_t) = 0$, is it true that $ Y_{\infty} \geq 0$ a.s.?

Note that $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} Y_t = Y_{\infty}$ exists, see Problem 3.16 (p. 18) in Karatzas and Shreve's *Brownian motion and stochastic calculus*. The remark below Definition 3.17 suggests that the answer to my question is "yes" but I do not see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the martingale context: if some random variables $Y_t$ and $Y_\infty$ are such that $Y_t\geqslant0$ almost surely for every $t$ and $Y_t\to Y_\infty$ almost surely, pointwise, when $t\to\infty$, then $Y_\infty\geqslant0$ almost surely, no?

Comment: Think you are correct, just I do not see how to prove it. Don't I need to interchange a probability and a limit? I.e. I am given that $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} P(Y_t \geq 0) = 0$ but I need  $P(\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} Y_t \geq 0) = 0$.

Comment: Sorry I meant $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} P(Y_t \geq 0) = 1$ and $P(\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} Y_t \geq 0) = 1$ in my comment.

Comment: This is deterministic result: if $x_t\geqslant0$ for every $t$ and $x_t\to x_\infty$ then $x_\infty\geqslant0$. Thus, for every $\omega$ such that $Y_t(\omega)\geqslant0$ for every $t$ and $Y_t(\omega)\to Y_\infty(\omega)$, one knows that $Y_\infty(\omega)\geqslant0$.